# Should I cash in my Token?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Since I want to earn a lot of money in Jetpack Joyride, I was wondering if cashing in Token at the end of a ride was more beneficial in the long term than gambling them.

Comment: Though it appears to be primary opinion based, I don't think it is because cashed in token bring a set amount of cash (that never changes) that you can compare to the risk of losing them in the jackpot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 6 out of 10 possible outcomes that can directly or otherwise enhance the amount of coins you can get off a token (Second Chance, Bonus, Cash Prize, Jackpot, Next Run Double, and Tokens all will potentially be worth more than 50 coins), and 4 either have no direct yield (miss) or have in my experience never gained anywhere close to 50 additional coins (750m head start, and all of the blast).
Realistically getting a single jackpot is worth selling 20 tokens (each token at 50 and jackpot at 1000 (50*20 = 1000), so that alone means that if you get one jack pot out of every 20 tokens spent you came out ahead.
If this were real life and you were at risk of losing actual money I would never recommend trying to make money off gambling, but at least for this game, gambling can actually be quite beneficial.

P.S. it is also worth note that the next run double effect does apply to selling your tokens, so if you have a double in effect and have stock piled a good number of tokens, it can translate to a good payout.